# How to replace the elements of one data frame if they match another data frame while keeping the ones that do not match?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm trying to replace some elements of my data frame if they match the elements of another data frame.

df1:

```
      V1        V2    V3
10 JP_00267-008 JP_00267-008 Line
11 JP_00302-049 JP_00302-049 Line
12      4FP3188      4FP3188 Line
13 JP_00284-029 JP_00284-029 Line
14 JP_00268-005 JP_00268-005 Line
15 JP_00265-057 JP_00265-057 Line
16 JP_00286-010 JP_00286-010 Line
17 JP_00283-008 JP_00283-008 Line
18 JP_00330-298 JP_00330-298 Line
19 JP_00269-035 JP_00269-035 Line
20 JP_00300-106 JP_00300-106 Line
```

df2:

```
      V1   V2
10 JP_00267-008 4FP3428 
11 JP_00302-049 4FP5103 
13 JP_00284-029 4FP4137 
14 JP_00268-005 4FP3465 
15 JP_00265-057 4FP3367 
16 JP_00286-010 4FP4245 
17 JP_00283-008 4FP4085 
18 JP_00330-298 4PP3992 
19 JP_00269-035 4FP3575 
20 JP_00300-106 4FP4963
```

What I want as output is:

```
      V1    V2  V3
10  4FP3428 JP_00267-008 Line
11  4FP5103 JP_00302-049 Line
12  4FP3188      4FP3188 Line
13  4FP4137 JP_00284-029 Line
14  4FP3465 JP_00268-005 Line
15  4FP3367 JP_00265-057 Line
16  4FP4245 JP_00286-010 Line
17  4FP4085 JP_00283-008 Line
18  4PP3992 JP_00330-298 Line
19  4FP3575 JP_00269-035 Line
20  4FP4963 JP_00300-106 Line
```

but what I get is:

```
      V1       V2         V3
10  4FP3428 JP_00267-008 Line
11  4FP5103 JP_00302-049 Line
12     <NA>      4FP3188 Line
13  4FP4137 JP_00284-029 Line
14  4FP3465 JP_00268-005 Line
15  4FP3367 JP_00265-057 Line
16  4FP4245 JP_00286-010 Line
17  4FP4085 JP_00283-008 Line
18  4PP3992 JP_00330-298 Line
19  4FP3575 JP_00269-035 Line
20  4FP4963 JP_00300-106 Line
```

This is the code that I used:

```
df1[,1] <- df2[match(as.character(unlist(df1[,1])), as.character(df2[[1]])), 2]
```

Can anyone help me to not have NA's and have the original element instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to stick with base R, use

```
# an index which includes missing values
idx <- match(as.character(unlist(df1[,1])), as.character(df2[[1]]))

# an index of the non-missing values in `idx`
idx_not_missing <- !is.na(idx)

# push the data only when the index `idx` is not missing 
df1[idx_not_missing,1] <- df2[idx[idx_not_missing], 2]
```

Comment: This dose not work! It gives the `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(35L, 1102L, 549L, 48L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`and generats an output with all NA's except for the only character that was not on the list!

Comment: Ok I figure out the problem was that the column were not as character. now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(df1), V1)[df2, V1:=i.V2][]
 #       V1           V2   V3
 # 1: 4FP3188      4FP3188 Line
 #2: 4FP3367 JP_00265-057 Line
 #3: 4FP3428 JP_00267-008 Line
 #4: 4FP3465 JP_00268-005 Line
 #5: 4FP3575 JP_00269-035 Line
 #6: 4FP4085 JP_00283-008 Line
 #7: 4FP4137 JP_00284-029 Line
 #8: 4FP4245 JP_00286-010 Line
 #9: 4FP4963 JP_00300-106 Line
#10: 4FP5103 JP_00302-049 Line
#11: 4PP3992 JP_00330-298 Line
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(df1, df2, by='V1') %>% 
           mutate(V2.y= ifelse(is.na(V2.y), V1, V2.y)) %>%
           select(-V1) %>% 
           rename(V1=V2.y, V2=V2.x)
 #            V2   V3      V1
 #1  JP_00267-008 Line 4FP3428
 #2  JP_00302-049 Line 4FP5103
 #3       4FP3188 Line 4FP3188
 #4  JP_00284-029 Line 4FP4137
 #5  JP_00268-005 Line 4FP3465
 #6  JP_00265-057 Line 4FP3367
 #7  JP_00286-010 Line 4FP4245
 #8  JP_00283-008 Line 4FP4085
 #9  JP_00330-298 Line 4PP3992
 #10 JP_00269-035 Line 4FP3575
 #11 JP_00300-106 Line 4FP4963
```